# Не получается импортировать код из одного js файла в другой js файл с помощью nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

**верстаю учебный проект, npm, nodejs, gulp все дела.**

у меня есть папка src/js в которой не малое количество разных js файлов(всякие слайдеры,попапы,обработка форм и т.д)

и в этой же папке есть файл main.js в который нужно импортировать некоторые плагины(те самые слайдера, попапы) и после импорта gulp должен минифицировать этот файл и закинуть в dest/js/main.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как это сделать ?
 подскажите плз :с

вот уже обработанный gulp-ом main.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
этот код require('плагин.js ...','...')
не работает.

а вот так должен выглядить dest/main.js,этот код работает, без всяких require(). этот файл из готового проекта и я хочу тоже чтобы мой файл выглядел также то есть код из файла а не require('файл')

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот gulpfile.js 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*надеюсь у меня получилось описать мою проблему подробно и понятно,
могу дополнить если еще что-то нужно. Спасибо. с:*

Answer (score 0):

**Разобрался, совсем забыл про gulp и его возможности, оказывается методы nodejs мне были совсем не нужны.
нужно было всего лишь вспомнить один из плагинов gulp**

*вот код который мне помог*

```
gulp.task('js',function(){
    return gulp.src([
        'src/js/jq-start.js',
        'src/js/forms.js',
        'src/js/script.js',
        'src/js/jq-end.js'])
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(babel({
        "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
      }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/js/'))
});
```